# Hosting multiple endpoints under WAS

Tags: wcf, binding, was

Is it possible to host a service with multiple binding endpoints under WAS. For example a service with tow TCP endpoints and tow message queue endpoints?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, no problem. The only rule is: you cannot have two endpoints with the same address and protocol, e.g. you cannot have two HTTP endpoint on localhost:8000.

Marc

Comment: but for message queue endpoint the svc file need to be the name of the queue... so how would you have two endpoint with two message queue binding to two diffrent queues?

Comment: Well, the Message Queue (MSMQ) case is a bit special - the svc file must be the same name as the queue --> so you'd have to have two svc files for queue1.svc and queue2.svc.